# JScrollPane not showing scrollbars when an Array of JPanels are added to it

Tags: java, swing

Im adding an array of JPanels inside a JScrollPane. The array of JPanels are being added to the JScrollPane but the scroll bars just wont show.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel panel_1;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 288, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 114, 434, 136);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel_1);
        scrollPane.setBounds(52, 57, 164, 126);
        scrollPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), "Histogram", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, Color.BLUE));
        scrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        buildBar();
    }

    JPanel[] barPanel;
    private void buildBar(){
        int x=0,y=22,w=100,h=80,s=10,n=3;   
        barPanel = new JPanel[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            barPanel[i] = new JPanel();
            barPanel[i].setBounds(x, y, w, h);
            barPanel[i].setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
            panel_1.add(barPanel[i]);
            panel_1.revalidate();
            panel_1.repaint();
            x = x + w + s;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been working on it for hours . Maybe there is something that I've missed out.

Answer (score 2):

You're shooting yourself in the foot with these two lines:

```
    panel_1.setBounds(10, 114, 434, 136);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);
```

Both of which will mess up the JScrollPane's ability to use and display scrollbars. What you need to do is: not to use setBounds but rather have the components use their preferredSize, and avoid using null layout, since this won't change the container's preferredSize.

Yet another reason to studiously avoid null layouts.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 388;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    public static final int INNER_PREF_W = 434;
    public static final int INNER_PREF_H = 126;
    private static final int HISTO_PANEL_COUNT = 6;
    private static final Dimension VP_SZ = new Dimension(164, 126);
    private JPanel holderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    public MyPanel2() {
        int w = INNER_PREF_W;
        int h = INNER_PREF_H;
        for (int i = 0; i < HISTO_PANEL_COUNT; i++) {
            holderPanel.add(new InnerPanel(w, h));
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(holderPanel);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(VP_SZ);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class InnerPanel extends JPanel {
        private int w;
        private int h;

        public InnerPanel(int w, int h) {
            this.w = w;
            this.h = h;
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = 0, y = 22, w = 100, h = 80, s = 10, n = 3;
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
                x = x + w + s;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
                return super.getPreferredSize();
            }
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyPanel2 mainPanel = new MyPanel2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPanel2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what should the setLayout() be subsituted with?

Comment: @JerrySangma: whatever works best. I have no idea what layout you're trying to achieve, but you should study the layout manager tutorial, experiment with and learn layouts, and see what you can come up with. But whatever you do, you should actively avoid using null layouts as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. And as you're finding out, the screw  you when you use them with JScrollPanes. See example above.

Comment: thanks for the example and tips...I'll try to work it out

Answer (score 2):

JScrollPane relies on the preferredSize of your container to determine the scroll bar width. If you use a Layout, the preferredSize will be determined for you when components are added to the panel.

However, when you use:

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

You are preventing the preferredSize from changing based on added components.

---

Try to use a layout which is applicable for your case.

In case you are very certain you do not want to use a Layout, in order to see the scroll bar, you may set the preferredSize of the container for every components you added by ***manually*** adjusting the preferredSize. That way, the scrollbar will still extend with newly added components.